# How can I retrieve a uploaded file's direct URL?

Tags: url, sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-clientobject

Hellu

Everything is in the title. The user of my program can upload files to a SharePoint server, how can I provide him a link to open this file? Meaning, how can I get the URL to put in the link?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Just to clarify, the File item I get after the upload only contains a ServerRelativeUrl propertie, which won't work for subsites.

Comment: How are you uploading the file? Please show some code

Comment: I don't think this will be relevant, as the upload uses numerous different functions in order to create a folder, import metadatas... I just get in the end my File object corresponding to the uploaded document, and I wanted to know if there was a way to get its URL. I have another bug so I couldn't try what I found: using the field EncodedAbsUrl.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Your SharePoint Site here" +"/"+ "ServerRelativeUrl");
```